# how do I set the compression level in tokudb

Tags: mysql, mariadb, configuration, compression, tokudb

Tokudb has various algorithms, [lmza, zlib, zstd etc](https://github.com/percona/tokudb-engine/wiki/Compression).
These algorithms have the ability to be configured. In that, you can set the compression level to a value between 1 and 10 depending on the algorithm.

How do I do this when creating a table using one of those compression algorithms, https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/tokudb/using_tokudb.html#tokudb-compression

https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/09/evaluating-database-compression-methods/

```
MariaDB [test]> create table t_zlib (x int, y int) compression=tokudb_zlib;

MariaDB [test]> show create table t_zlib;
CREATE TABLE `t_zlib` (
  `x` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `y` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=TokuDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 `compression`=tokudb_zlib
```

Comment: Perhaps you could/should also change `INT` (4 bytes) to `MEDIUMINT` or `SMALLINT` (3 or 2 bytes).  This might give compression a slight head-start.